# Docker sync on Mac and Symfony still slow and sync suddenly stops

Tags: macos, symfony, docker, unison

I'm working on a Mac with Symfony PHP framework. Without docker-sync response time for basic app (symfony 3.4) it takes me around 20sec to load. With docker-sync its much faster (about 3sec), but it's not working quite the best.

I had to downgrade to Docker 17.07.x in order to make docker-sync to work. More info about that can be found here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/517

Second thing is when using native_osx or unison as strategy on Mojave sync stops at random time. This is due APFS (apple's file system) and unison (which is also used by native_osx), more info here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/515.

So, at this moment I couldn't find a way to make my docker faster or even to work with docker on Mac.

When using xDebug it takes ages to refresh a page (due to high reading on filesystem) or even 504 due to timeout.

What are advices for using Docker on Mac?

Comment: I just found this article but I didn't test it https://blog.jetpulp.fr/docker-mac-optimisations-php-developpers/

Comment: Hi! I want to know if yo finally found a way to make your docker faster. I'm stuck trying to make a Symfony + Vue environment faster... Thank you in advance! @mario